# How to create a C# project using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I want to try Visual Studio Code to compile the typical "Hello World" in C#. I did the following:

- I installed Visual Studio Code.
- I added the extension C# for Visual Studio Code (OmniSharp).
- I installed the 64-bit SDK 2.1.10.
- I created a folder to contain the project I want to create.
- I opened the folder with Visual Studio Code. On the terminal I wrote:

```
dotnet new console
```

but, unlike the tutorials I see on the web,
nothing happens. The project is not created but I do not see any
error messages either.

I appreciate the help to know how to create, edit and compile a project in C# from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Just curious, why dont you install visual studio community edition? It's free.

Comment: @VincentElbertBudiman maybe OP is not a windows user or maybe vsc is too heavy for his system.

Comment: You should open your folder by pressing Ctrl + K, O -> then select your folder.

Comment: @Alberto did you install dotnet core? Can you try `dotnet new console -o myApp` in your terminal?

Comment: Have you installed .NET Core SDK? And did you try running the command `dotnet new console` from a terminal, instead of running from the terminal in vs code?

Comment: If I try to run the command dotnet new console in the Visual Studio terminal, I don't see any answer but if I do it in a Windows console I can see an error saying that there is no api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll installed.

Comment: After installing an update proposed by Microsoft to solve the problem, I try again to execute the dotnet new console instruction but now an error message appears with the text "the library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C: \ Program files \ dotnet \ hosts \ fxr \ 2.0.7 \ hostfxr.dll failed "

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late one, but I hope it helps.
I assume that you have .Net already installed, you can check by opening the **`cmd`** and run the command **`dotnet --version`**
I also assume that you have installed Visual Studio.
Here are a few steps I took to run the C# code using visual studio.

1. Install code runner:
   Go to the **`extensions`** on your visual studio, click on **`Extensions`** icon. On the search field, type **`Code Runner`**, choose the first option and click on the **`install`**
2. Navigate to settings from **`File > Preferences > Settings`** from Visual Studio
3. Search for **`run in terminal`** and scroll down the page. Enable the Run in terminal for the code runner as shown in the image Below.

[image: Run in Terminal - Code Runner]

4. Now click on **`Open Settings JSON`** button shown in the Top right (second after the run icon) as shown below

[image: Open Settings JSON]

The resulting window is as below. Add a comma (,) at the end of the existing setting, then type `code runner`, choose the option with **`code-runner.executorMap`**

[image: Code Runner Executor Map]

5. Scroll down the List, where there is the key csharp. Replace the value scriptcs with `cd $dir && dotnet run $fileName`

[image: Select executorMap]

6. Save all the changed - `File>Save` or `Ctrl+S`

Yey!!! You can now run your code by clicking the `run button` or using `code runner`

Answer (score 0):

You can see if you’ve got SDK properly installed using `dotnet version` and seeing if the version provided is the one you installed.

Just to be sure you can restart computer to make sure a new PATH variables will be used - that was an issue in one of my previous work laptops :)

Good tutorial on first .NET (Core is obsolete since version 5) is here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install. Every step is in detail there - it’s a good starting point for you :)

For creating a new project: `dotnet new <project type>`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Btw: .NET Core SDK 2.1 will reach End of Support on August, 21. I suggest installing a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have DOTNET installed on your computer.
Open the terminal and then run `dotnet new console`

This is going to create some projects and a simple hello world C# application. It will take some time..

You can code some c# in the `Program.cs` file and then open the terminal and type `dotnet run` and press enter.

If it doesn't work and it shows `command not found`, make sure you have installed .NET sdk .

Hopefully it helps.